# How to compare each and every value in String array list in android

Tags: java, android, for-loop

```
`for (int j = 0; j < multiFilterArr.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mBusServicesModels.size(); i++) {
            try {
                if (b == true) {
                        if (mBusServicesModels.get(i).getBus_type().toLowerCase().startsWith(multiFilterArr[j].toLowerCase())) {

                            //apply logic here
                        } else {
                            //apply logic here
                        }

                } else {
                    if (mBusServicesModels.get(i).getBus_type().toLowerCase().contains(multiFilterArr[j].toLowerCase())) {

                //apply logic here
                    } else {
              //apply logic here
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }`
```

In  the above code i am having multi Filter Arr where i will insert strings that contains or starts with the get Bus Type string value. What i want to do is whenever i insert or remove string value in multi Filter Array that string will be compared and the entire data need to be captured

Answer (score 0):

`BottomNavigation` and `TabLayout` are meant to be used for Navigation (moving from one Page to other). They are supposed to be selected Only one at a time. So they are not suitable for your purpose.

You should use `CheckBox` for your purpose. You can have Check Boxes for **AC, Non-AC, Seater, Sleeper, All** in one row and **price, duration, time** in another row. 
You can then check which checkboxes are checked and filter the data accordingly.

If you want to allow only single selection, you can use `RadioButton (RadioGroup)` instead of Checkbox.

Hope it helps